# Is it possible to Log data for a particular function in a Function app containing multiple functions?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

I want to save cost on Log analytics.
I have a function app with 4 functions in it. I want to log only for a particular function and not for all.

Answer (score 0):

I have created 3 azure functions in azure function app in visual studio:

Then i used this in my **host.json** file:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "Function.TimerTrigger1.User": "Information",
      "Function": "Error"
    }
  }
}
```

*TimerTrigge1 is Function name*

After using this i am able to only see the logs of TimerTrigger1 Function:

[image]

Then you can publish your function app to Azure then from now on you can only see the required function app logs.

[image]